# Remote working. Is my employer able to monitor my activity

Tags: privacy, proxy, tor, sniffing

Due to situation, my employer made a work-from-home policy.
And remote administration tool is not installed, since I did clean installation of the system.

Is my employer able to see my activity?

Let's say that I use my company email.
What steps shall one take to secure his activity?

P. S. Don't write "You'll break company policy." and related, I'm asking from technical standpoint.

Comment: What do you mean a clean install of the system? What OS are you using and how to do access work related material?

Comment: I formated the harddrive, installed Linux on it, made my firewall only allow http, https, dns protocols to allow me to surf the net. And I login to gmail suite.

Answer (score 2):

Given a clean install of a public distribution of Linux on your own computer, I should say that your employer can monitor  the activity you do with gmail suite, but not any other activity on your computer. That is, if you login to gmail suite your employer can track when you log in, when you log out, when you are reading document, writing documents, and either explicitly or implicitly when you are idle (not doing any work related activity).

Comment: Can they see my history or real time activity?